# Best workflow for local debugging python / flask / google app engine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask

I'm developing a small web-app using python + flask + google app engine.  I was just wondering if anyone has found a better debugging workflow (with a local server) than me?

At the moment, I'm stuck between two sub-optimal approaches:

**1.  Use local GAE server: `dev_appserver.py app.yaml`**

- Con: only gives very minimal python error information

**2.  Use flask server: `python main.py`**

- Con: doesn't reload when files changed
- Con: can't accept the same folder structure for serving local files as dev_appserver.py

My current workflow is to use dev_appserver.py until I run into python errors, at which point I edit main.py, quit dev_appserver.py, run the flask server, edit the browser address, and continue.

I've tried playing with the different dev_appserver.py logging settings, but that doesn't seem to influence whether python error messages are sent to the terminal window.

Comment: Flask development server does have auto-reload option Check: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/quickstart/#debug-mode

Comment: Thanks.  I've added another con (!) - that the flask server doesn't seem to be able to accept the same folder structure when serving static files.  For example, with GAE, I've got a nested static folder structure (`/static/js`, `/static/css`, etc.) which doesn't work with flask.  So when I switch to flask, locally-served js and css files don't load, without even more faffing around.

Comment: Could you include the folder structure you're using? Flask works correctly with `/static/js/` , at least for me.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might solve your problem:

```
app = Flask(__name__)

production_environment = os.getenv('SERVER_SOFTWARE').startswith('Google App Engine/')

if not production_environment:
    app.debug = True
```